# Unable to insert data into SQL Server Database ODBC C++

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, insert, odbc

I have been trying to insert a record into the sql server database using odbc but having some issue.The program below is code using a console c++ on visual studio.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    RETCODE rc;
    HENV henv;
    HDBC hdbc;
    HSTMT hstmt;
    SDWORD cdData;

    cout << "Attempting Connection " << endl;

    SQLAllocEnv(&henv);
    SQLAllocConnect(henv, &hdbc);
    rc = SQLConnect(hdbc, L"DatasourceTest", SQL_NTS, 0, SQL_NTS, 0, SQL_NTS);

    if ((rc != SQL_SUCCESS) && (rc != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    {
        cout << "Cannot open database -- make sure ODBC is confugured properly." << endl;
        SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
        SQLFreeEnv(henv);
        cout << "Press ENTER to continue." << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Connected -- ODBC is confugured properly." << endl;
    }

    //Create a SQL statement




    UCHAR  szSqlStr[] = "INSERT INTO PERSONS (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('Jack', 'Benson')";
    cout << "Executing " << szSqlStr << endl;
    rc = SQLAllocStmt(hdbc, &hstmt);
    rc = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR*)szSqlStr, sizeof(szSqlStr));
    rc = SQLExecute(hstmt);

    cout << "rc" << rc << endl;
    cout << "SQL_SUCCESS" << SQL_SUCCESS << endl;
    cout << "SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO" << SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO << endl;



    if ((rc != SQL_SUCCESS) && (rc != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    {
        //ERROR 
        SQLWCHAR sqlState[8];
        SQLWCHAR msgText[1024];
        SQLINTEGER NativeErrorPtr;
        SQLSMALLINT TextLengthPtr;
        SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, 1, sqlState, &NativeErrorPtr, msgText, sizeof(msgText), &TextLengthPtr);

        SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_DROP);
        SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
        SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
        SQLFreeEnv(henv);
        cout << "Error " << endl << msgText << endl;
        cout << "Press ENTER to continue." << endl;


    }


    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I have attached the output of the program in this thread. The RETCODE returned was -1 and there is this error seen in the screenshot. I am unable to insert any record into the database. The connection to the database was alright. The error code was different every time the program was executed.

Comment: I'd try `SQLExecDirect` instead. (Since the statement has no parameters.)

Comment: I have tried using SQLExecDirect but it turns out having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The primary error is that you pass the ANSI string to the unicode version of SQLPrepare.

```
UCHAR  szSqlStr[] = "INSERT INTO PERSONS (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('Jack', 'Benson')";
...
rc = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR*)szSqlStr, sizeof(szSqlStr));
```

Change the character set of your program to ANSI or turn the request string into unicode. Also you should take into account that last parameter take length in symbols not bytes